# Creating SVG out of World of Warcraft XML

Tags: xml, svg, world-of-warcraft

WoW uses, in addition to the Lua language, also the XML markup for the creation of the graphical interface. Since the SVG files are pure XML, is it possible to draw vector images using World of Warcraft XML and then use them in the interface?
This is the schema of the in-game XML:

```
<Ui
     xmlns="http://www.blizzard.com/wow/ui/" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.blizzard.com/wow/ui/..\FrameXML\UI.xsd">
        
     <!-- All GUI elements here -->
        
  </Ui>
```

Comment: SVG contains URL to images.  So you can save you vector images as a standard image file and use the file location as the URL.

Comment: I inserted the game XML schema

Comment: Not this way. XML just means you have nodes, elements and attributes. Their names and structure is described by the schema connected with the **namespace** `xmlns`. The value for WoW is `http://www.blizzard.com/wow/ui/`, the one for SVG is `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`. It's a different language, just with the same grammar. You have to translate one into the other. (Note: asking for a translating tool or software is out of scope on this site.)

Comment: Look at UI.xsd which has an INCLUDE to other schemas : https://github.com/tomrus88/BlizzardInterfaceCode/blob/master/Interface/FrameXML/UI.xsd

Answer (score -1):

I found sample of SVG file Here : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8f/Activision_Blizzard_Studios.svg

Here is the source

```
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="1000px" height="283.835px" viewBox="0 -29.852 1000 283.835" enable-background="new 0 -29.852 1000 283.835" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M538.348,119.919c-4.744,0-8.591,3.855-8.591,8.598c0,4.74,3.847,8.592,8.591,8.592c4.745,0,8.604-3.852,8.604-8.592  C546.952,123.774,543.093,119.919,538.348,119.919 M538.348,135.245c-3.709,0-6.728-3.016-6.728-6.729  c0-3.715,3.019-6.738,6.728-6.738c3.72,0,6.742,3.023,6.742,6.738C545.09,132.229,542.066,135.245,538.348,135.245 M179.057,131.399  h20.773V52.237h-20.773V131.399z M499.503,82.418l-37.597-32.365v81.235l20.87,0.074V97.919l37.434,36.658V52.51h-20.707V82.418  L499.503,82.418z M115.389,112.201c-11.238,0-20.348-9.11-20.348-20.337c0-11.237,9.109-20.338,20.348-20.338  c4.983,0,9.549,1.789,13.086,4.755l13.445-15.262c-7.121-6.128-16.396-9.833-26.536-9.833c-22.474,0-40.696,18.208-40.696,40.678  c0,22.469,18.223,40.672,40.696,40.672c10.224,0,19.566-3.75,26.714-9.98l-13.445-15.269  C125.09,110.341,120.458,112.201,115.389,112.201 M366.12,24.676H263.307l-23.938,62.508L215.43,24.676H109.248L98.203,45.459h47.57  l-0.023,85.999h21.439l0.063-85.999h32.838l39.28,104.31l39.282-104.31h98.811L366.12,24.676z M327.497,70.922  c1.075-1.527,4.908-1.527,4.908-1.527h13.344V52.209h-21.625c-7.064,0-17.501,4.291-17.501,18.713  c0,19.019,23.479,31.451,21.174,39.116c-1.091,3.67-5.523,3.832-7.826,3.832h-14.264v17.492h23.318  c9.974,0,19.952-6.133,19.952-17.795C348.979,91.314,321.708,79.203,327.497,70.922 M278.957,131.356h20.776v-79.16h-20.776V131.356  z M352.333,131.372h20.779V52.209h-20.779V131.372z M540.769,128.423v-0.025c1.003-0.402,1.442-1.211,1.442-2.27  c0-1.375-1.034-2.506-2.654-2.506h-4.882v9.061h1.984v-3.539h2.001c0.997,0,1.361,0.42,1.507,1.373  c0.104,0.725,0.073,1.6,0.314,2.166h1.988c-0.354-0.502-0.34-1.576-0.38-2.143C542.025,129.626,541.755,128.669,540.769,128.423   M538.841,127.728h-2.182v-2.555h2.182c0.891,0,1.37,0.389,1.37,1.254C540.211,127.335,539.73,127.728,538.841,127.728 M0,131.663  h22.094l5.524-14.727h25.778l5.525,14.727h22.094L40.506,15.692L0,131.663z M33.909,95.765l6.143-20.239l6.134,20.239H33.909z   M417.676,51.1c-22.519,0-40.763,18.251-40.763,40.749c0,22.506,18.245,40.762,40.763,40.762c22.512,0,40.766-18.256,40.766-40.762  C458.44,69.351,440.188,51.1,417.676,51.1 M417.676,112.087c-11.183,0-20.245-9.052-20.245-20.238  c0-11.177,9.063-20.231,20.245-20.231c11.188,0,20.253,9.055,20.253,20.231C437.929,103.035,428.864,112.087,417.676,112.087   M575.813-29.852c-1.155,0-2.068,0.593-2.068,1.32v221.493c0,0.732,0.913,1.318,2.068,1.318c1.14,0,2.062-0.586,2.062-1.318V-28.531  C577.873-29.259,576.951-29.852,575.813-29.852 M790.278,103.354l0.031-0.913h-4.573l-0.09,0.295l-1.398,3.022  c-0.323,1.32-0.868,2.466-2.941,3.557l-1.06-1.543l-0.792,0.631c-1.475,1.356-2.36,4.403-2.595,5.883  c-4.534,0.564-7.702,5.428-9.813,8.818c-0.755,1.213-1.697,2.74-2.113,2.926c-2.728,1.277-4.336,1.297-5.289,1.307l-1.204,0.16  l-4.292,2.252l-2.537,1.014l-0.995,0.07l-0.138,0.031l-0.563-0.768c1.119-1.791,2.77-6.191,4.963-12.264  c1.127-3.111,2.394-6.636,2.756-7.125l0.166-0.237l0.17-0.308v-3.701c0.13-2.151,7.068-21.02,11.47-22.889l0.672-0.289l-0.154-0.726  c-0.146-0.645-0.371-2.069-0.371-3.455c0-0.854,0.08-1.698,0.326-2.326c0.894-2.35,4.896-4.454,6.361-5.063l0.546-0.227v-6.705  c0.93-1.142,1.746-3.227,2.74-5.963c1.423-3.908,3.185-8.777,5.553-10.479l0.513-0.36l-0.174-0.601  c-0.003-0.031-0.468-1.701-0.468-3.592c0-1.594,0.331-3.343,1.552-4.377l0.322-0.264v-25.23l-0.863-2.186l-0.51-1.15V2.664  L743.43,2.498l0.146,1.019c0.133,0.881-0.663,2.33-1.196,3.04l-0.178,0.231v13.321l1.624,1.308c2.078,2.121,0.563,7.799-0.193,9.813  l-0.089,0.227l0.38,0.781l0.17,0.923l0.121,0.923l0.8,4.991l0.309,0.226c1.099,0.787,1.051,1.09,0.97,1.686  c-0.158,1.016-0.17,2.031,1.33,3.428l0.786,0.736l0.606-0.984c2.117-3.438,2.836-4.599,2.836-5.582V27.465  c0-1.488,3.477-3.187,4.596-3.187h0.89v-0.885c0-5.615,3.237-7.222,5.836-8.521c0,0,1.392-0.916,2.041-1.339  c0.355,0.011,13.19,0.138,14.734,0.149v8.777c-2.283,2.168-3.904,4.446-5.294,6.453c-1.338,1.939-2.498,3.617-3.934,4.655  c-0.788,1.601-1.029,3.38-1.029,4.98c0,2.156,0.389,3.707,0.573,4.36c-4.198,3.97-5.196,6.164-5.391,7.104  c-0.466,0.354-3.379,2.603-3.379,2.603c-2.502,3.815-5.165,17.17-5.278,17.741c-4.615,4.808-5.214,8.42-5.545,10.358l-0.194,0.916  c-0.008-0.043-3.31,3.727-4.792,6.645l-1.366,5.088c-0.246,1.562-0.47,3.031-1.106,3.488l-0.314,0.218l-0.058,0.537l-0.614,4.854  c-0.429,2.384-0.904,5.007-0.904,7.432c0,0.78,0.048,1.54,0.157,2.26c0.169,0.331,0.934,1.358,0.934,2.688  c0,0.674-0.194,1.424-0.769,2.203l-0.528,0.701l0.73,0.547c0.59,0.439,2.238,3.893,2.376,4.563l0.041,1.02l-1.043,0.76l-0.354,0.268  l-0.024,0.461v8.494c-0.986,0.922-2.045,2.004-2.045,2.596l0.711,1.688l1.051,1.334l0.493,0.076h10.313  c1.49,1.492,4.248,2.139,4.573,2.203c1.675,0.021,2.328-0.914,2.799-1.594c0.527-0.756,0.944-1.357,2.521-1.357l1.329-0.078  l0.198-0.063l0.962,1.436l0.599,0.201h15.56l0.259-0.42c0.761-1.225,4.065-2.543,4.745-2.547l0.917-0.02l-0.045-0.91  c-0.501-9.045-0.68-19.104-0.09-20.279l1.192-2.189c0.303-0.938,0.461-1.414,1.491-1.689l0.97-0.263l-0.384-0.935  C790.242,109.335,790.222,104.913,790.278,103.354 M848.765,131.284c0-1.424-0.76-2.336-1.418-3.148l-1.051-1.383l-0.481-0.068  h-6.462c-0.385-0.408-1.943-2.098-1.943-2.098l-0.569,1.039c-2.219,3.592-3.899,4.264-6.229,5.197l-5.178,2.691l-2.193,0.793  c-1.859,0.564-4.17,1.25-5.479,2.67c-1.092,1.172-1.281,2.57-1.423,3.598c-0.152,1.135-0.233,1.271-0.502,1.32l-2.893,0.307  c-1.608,0.287-2.883,0.502-4.435-0.24l-0.687-0.328l-0.57,0.865l-0.586,0.859l-0.563-0.438c0.234-0.617,1.192-3.117,1.192-3.117  c0.393-0.758,1.289-3.004,1.289-4.463l-0.045-0.279c1.07-1.467,4.292-7.213,4.918-11.439l0.009-7.229l4.065-11.5l0.048-15.471  c0.47-1.927,1.31-2.772,2.195-3.666l1.866-2.715l0.044-4.911c1.884-2.082,2.692-5.082,3.33-7.807c0.47-1.99,0.958-4.048,1.782-4.636  l0.363-0.252l0.417-13.604c-0.085-0.442-0.117-0.857-0.117-1.25c0-1.449,0.497-2.592,1.087-3.961l1.276-3.712l1.452-8.558  c0.075-1.391,0.497-1.655,1.126-2.057l1.593-1.889c0.203-0.691,0.263-1.527,0.263-2.316c0-1.102-0.107-1.94-0.182-2.43l0.804-0.766  c1.925-1.821,2.566-2.434,3.229-4.891c0.187-0.69,0.237-1.515,0.237-2.293c0-1.18-0.108-2.092-0.174-2.523  c2.474-2.574,3.625-5.405,4.421-7.514l1.25-2.696l0.117-0.384V2.568l-1.723,0.046l-0.068,0.024l-0.998-1.497l-0.493-0.03  l-34.965-0.027l-11.341,0.027h-0.881l0.048,0.883v24.858c-1.317,1.245-2.072,2.37-2.072,3.298l0.384,2.006  c0.17,0.553,0.332,1.094,0.332,1.814c0,0.72-0.162,1.617-0.654,2.9l-0.224,0.575l2.699,2.326l0.821-0.646  c0.67-1.088,1.099-1.067,1.811-1.039c2.514,0.121,3.79-1.205,5.168-9.647c1.379-8.403,3.649-11.399,4.276-11.483l1.467-0.305  c1.479-0.402,3.961-1.085,5.084,0.044l1.026,1.449l0.631,0.293h6.801l0.401,0.442l0.119,0.104l0.01,0.054  c0,0.178-0.105,0.518-0.954,1.102l-0.394,0.269l-0.016,0.481v4.49c-3.859,3.886-9.599,16.768-9.599,18.104v3.965  c-0.271,2.474-1.782,5.114-2.872,7.044l-1.219,2.577l-0.022,1.338l0.016,1c0,1.997-1.794,3.806-1.813,3.821l-0.229,0.232  l-0.085,1.06l0.103,1.485l0.998,1.228l0.322,0.324l-8.159,21.551c-0.116,0.484-1.386,6.82-1.386,13.537  c0,3.5,0.348,7.093,1.378,10.023l0.748,1.43l0.573,1.625c0.012,0.146,0.493,2.9,0.493,5.76c0,1.41-0.113,2.832-0.461,3.98  l-0.864,2.109l-0.542,1.482c0.267,0.848,0.469,1.863,0.469,2.686c0,0.518-0.085,0.945-0.283,1.209l-1.269,1.072l-0.263,0.814  c0.133,0.502,0.344,1.584,0.344,2.604c0,0.594-0.073,1.172-0.275,1.588l-1.838,1.84l-1.165,0.816l0.231,0.621  c0.201,0.6,0.46,1.693,0.46,2.635c0,0.551-0.089,1.053-0.319,1.338l-1.176,0.994l-0.389,0.68v5.186l-0.08,0.768  c-0.058,0.43-0.134,0.963-0.134,1.545c0,1.135,0.278,2.502,1.468,3.787l0.262,0.285h0.388c1.885,0,4.111-0.953,5.897-1.725  l2.161-0.834l3.947-0.084l7.04-0.154c2.095-0.674,4.147-2.068,5.444-3.449c0.662,0.063,6.947,0.742,6.947,0.742l-0.089,0.105  l0.443,0.934l0.275,0.393l0.488,0.049h20.725l0.061-1.738l0.975-0.654l0.352-0.268l0.024-0.453v-12.584l-0.573-1.652l-0.801-2.801  c0-1.844,0.483-2.441,0.828-2.877L848.765,131.284z M707.495,7.729c0.59,0.841,1.2,0.964,2.78,0.995  c0.514,1.008,1.552,1.576,2.609,1.881c1.521,0.445,2.543,0.816,2.834,1.93v0.004l1.733,29.465l0.023,0.487l1.277,0.683  c-0.376,0.254-1.358,0.953-1.358,0.953l0.058,0.418l0.443,58.353c-1.18,1.473-1.821,4.123-1.821,5.723l0.94,3.283l0.438,1.172  l0.053,1.373l-1.382,1.131l-0.049,0.461c0,0.025,0.008,0.414,0.008,1.057c0,3.43-0.102,14.217-1.16,17.486l-0.484,0.34l-3.357,2.938  l-2.841,3.852l0.657,0.627l1.004,0.908l1.216,0.721c0.622,0.791,1.616-0.018,4.001-2.389c2.166-0.865,14.063-1.273,15.444-0.35  l0.355,0.23l0.524-0.182l2.006-0.635c0.453,0.141,0.994,0.135,0.994,0.135l3.491,0.602l0.009-1.156l-0.603-4.313l-6.535-4.189  c-2.223-1.262-2.271-1.285-2.926-4.037l-0.263-0.99c-0.448-1.625-0.651-2.521,0.093-3.436l1.196-0.988l0.363-0.611l0.734-10.197  l-0.282-0.348c-0.444-0.578-1.786-4.447-1.818-5.087l-0.864-6.001c-0.263-0.94-0.457-1.653-0.457-2.292  c0-0.752,0.279-1.397,1.071-2.19l1.563-1.261l0.053-0.355v-5.844l-0.322-0.492l-0.18-2.271l-0.093-1.699L728.334,79l0.008-0.308  c0-0.522-0.061-1.308-0.061-1.308c-0.077-0.617-0.158-1.358-0.158-2.116c0-1.142,0.198-2.3,0.913-3.095l1.621-1.291l-0.017-0.563  l-0.672-3.795l-0.307-0.493l-0.348-1.615c-0.146-0.939-0.371-1.678-0.729-2.24c0.448-3.004,0.614-7.494,0.614-12.453  c0-6.086-0.227-12.791-0.404-18.042l-0.218-8.257c0-0.414,0.137-0.539,0.599-0.897c0.589-0.456,1.47-1.138,1.47-2.808  c0-1.596-0.277-2.291-1.109-2.731l-0.271-1.711c0-2.567,3.499-5.317,6.636-6.188l0.646-0.178V5.7l-0.771-0.932l-1.459-1.958  l-0.672,0.148c-2.352,0.877-22.315,0.857-25.447-0.023l-0.586-0.158l-0.43,0.582l-1.762,2.359l0.646,0.637L707.495,7.729z   M879.858,75.834l0.04-0.533l0.375-7.738v-0.455l-0.366-0.261c-0.854-0.616-1.043-0.919-1.043-1.239l0.041-0.355l0.111-0.855  c0-0.732-0.396-1.602-1.471-2.702v-6.042l-1.365-1.082l-4.386-16.949c-1.414-3.634-4.987-13.434-4.987-16.367v-4.072l-0.787-1.844  c-0.663-0.797-1.883-2.271-4.081-7.049l-0.26-1.441c-0.34-2.516-0.97-7.219-4.66-7.219l-2.295,0.85  c-0.908,0.912-1.025,2.313-1.025,3.763l0.016,1.374c0,2.055-0.21,2.789-1.144,2.908c-0.38,0.137-2.393,2.182-2.393,2.182  l-1.116,1.205l-0.129,0.458v5.656c-0.448,0.603-2.068,2.787-2.068,2.787l-0.569,1.125c-1.477,2.661-2.713,6.84-2.951,7.673  l-0.255,0.178l-1.058,0.928c-0.461,0.6-0.61,1.195-0.61,1.75c0,0.533,0.133,1.029,0.254,1.478l0.188,1.851  c-1.298,1.332-2.19,3.203-3.098,5.238l-0.604,1.346c-1.107,2.43-1.321,5.17-1.508,7.582c-0.21,2.888-0.403,5.379-2.009,6.322  l-0.44,0.266v0.5c0,4.258-1.503,7.512-1.52,7.545l-1.038,1.668l-1.601,3.088l-0.131,3.551l-0.048,3.744  c-0.331,2.21,0.259,2.96,1.245,3.398l0.097,0.027l0.008,0.083c0,0.746-0.125,0.899-0.984,1.508l-0.381,0.257v5.949l-0.146,0.112  l-1.016,0.865c-0.694,0.809-0.925,1.947-0.925,3.074c0,1.694,0.483,3.215,0.671,3.778c-0.291,0.772-0.695,2.611-1.321,8.075  l-0.053,0.484l0.586,0.44l0.837,0.675c-0.009,0.219-0.849,0.676-1.366,0.963l-2.805,2.271c-1.075,1.853-1.266,4.851-1.29,5.667  c-0.5,0.557-5.181,5.875-5.181,5.875l0.359,0.592l0.868,1.834l1.371,3.459l0.76-0.43l13.935-4.961  c1.446-0.408,7.558-0.207,11.309,0.039l0.558,0.037l0.371-0.756l1.317-2.408c0.445-0.582,0.825-1.066,0.825-1.592l-0.081-0.389  l-0.089-0.258l-0.828-0.488l-1.701-1.227c-0.623-0.607-1.363-1.127-2.175-1.436v-7.182c-0.024-0.185-0.614-1.967-1.026-3.197h1.948  c0.9,0.87,2.8,1.969,6.142,3.803c3.246,1.771,9.991,5.457,10.008,6.767c-0.393,11.915-8.576,20.821-8.666,20.909l-0.233,0.252v0.355  c0,3.754,2.385,6.154,4.313,8.074c1.362,1.363,2.542,2.545,2.542,3.789v4.064l4.146,13.588l-0.04,8.875l1.988-0.859l0.613,0.393  l1.648-0.801l1.213-1.096l0.08-0.455v-5.895l1.302-1.059l0.065-0.461v-4.641c0.957-1.195,1.535-3.029,2.027-4.906  c0.466-1.717,0.981-3.658,1.714-4.193l0.363-0.26v-8.041c1.822-2.053,3.084-5.832,4.171-9.305c0.72-2.33,1.633-5.229,2.319-5.715  l0.259-0.201l0.085-0.314c0.433-1.746,0.61-9.336,0.61-16.917c0-7.295-0.162-14.581-0.408-16.73  C881.298,89.439,879.858,78.61,879.858,75.834 M864.315,94.977c-0.541,0.04-1.059,0.04-1.715,0  c-2.956-0.931-5.107-3.646-8.906-4.446c-3.131-0.667-6.305-0.332-8.221,0c0,0-0.021-0.743,1.366-1.106  c0.626-2.271-0.517-10.035,0-12.964c1.204-1.254,1.366-9.203,1.366-9.203c3.168-0.217,1.818-3.557,4.122-5.188l0.311-9.21  c0,0,1.362,5.197,3.3,7.294c1.611,1.748,3.737,0.932,5.638,2.653c2.304,2.077,1.297,9.336,2.739,10.371  C864.793,76.119,864.315,94.977,864.315,94.977 M783.433,147.399l-0.856-0.023c-13.766-0.457-45.994-1.229-48.063,1.553  c-4.691,3.273-10.075,1.754-14.012,0.643c-1.944-0.541-3.346-0.941-4.376-0.688l-1.152,0.676c0,0-2.162,2.082-2.764,2.658  c-3.17,0.477-5.267,0.34-7.462,0.17c0,0-2.072-0.111-3.063-0.152c-0.152-2.287-0.702-3.281-1.342-3.809l-0.017-0.008l0.061-0.266  l1.035-1.76l0.143-0.223l0.229-0.502v-8.842l1.321-1.066l0.061-0.461v-5.906l0.408-0.369c0.897-0.781,0.966-1.074,0.966-2.615  l-0.578-2.234l-0.711-0.908c0.129-0.414,0.279-0.914,0.279-0.914c0.398-1.467,0.585-1.947,1.629-2.117l0.723-0.113l0.021-0.723  c0.016-0.422,0.113-2.963,0.113-5.113c0-1.236-0.033-2.348-0.135-2.865l-0.061-0.322l-1.334-1.068c0,0,0.041-8.737,0.053-9.509  l1.266-1.043l0.098-0.432c0.105-1.728,0.729-12.061,0.729-20.229c0-4.672-0.202-8.628-0.825-9.862l-1.697-1.873l-0.941-0.746V37.547  l1.298-1.059l0.076-0.469v-6.381l-0.371-0.27c-2.3-1.66-2.389-2.5-2.389-2.512c0.004-0.818,0.105-0.96,1.006-1.598l0.38-0.262  V10.746l-0.372-0.265c-1.49-1.071-4.833-5.058-5.992-6.505l-1.907-0.303c-0.752,0.178-1.683,0.406-3.5-2.567l-0.268-0.426h-11.009  c-0.259-0.38-0.979-1.415-0.979-1.415l-0.509-0.066h-2.319l-0.263,0.725l-0.604,1.535l-1.241,1.396l0.821,0.538  c5.108,3.68,5.729,5.4,6.021,6.22l1.188,1.63l0.42-0.273c2.752-0.103,3.022,0.515,3.022,0.539c0.076,0.148,2.036,3.83,2.353,7.541  v0.102c0,1.3-1.6,5.533-2.223,6.318l-0.525,0.688l2.004,1.627c0.064,0.396,0.099,1.083,0.099,1.924c0,2.326-0.224,5.715-0.363,7.399  l-0.833,0.837l-1.843,1.688l-0.09,0.459v11.166l1.375,1.104v20.808l0.388,0.261c0.364,0.249,1.257,1.366,1.357,2.438l0.009,0.202  c0,1.245-1.052,2.706-1.375,2.927l-0.371,0.269l-0.008,0.462v14.8c-0.01-0.384-0.986,0.396-0.986,0.396l-0.268,0.214l-0.112,0.37  c-0.018,0.131-0.355,2.167-0.355,5.125c0,1.416,0.104,3.083,0.331,4.826l-0.13,0.225l-1.066,0.85l-0.192,0.546l0.032,18.68  l0.379,0.256c1.241,0.879,2.369,1.797,2.369,3.361l0.04,1.105l-1.043,0.756l-0.349,0.271l-0.022,0.453v4.807  c0-0.395-0.971,0.375-0.971,0.375l-0.348,0.258l-0.057,0.484v11.195l0.42,0.303c0.707,0.506,0.953,0.721,0.953,1.104  c0,0.439-0.411,0.752-0.849,1.027l-0.413,0.258l-0.111,0.57v5.881c-0.478,0.402-3.169,2.643-3.169,2.643l-1.563,1.342l-3.706,1.932  l-0.292,0.17l-0.156,0.453l-0.609,1.551l-1.112,1.254l0.704,0.68l1.604,1.746l0.744-0.23c1.754-1.088,8.35-0.498,12.084,0.117  l0.72,0.121l0.238-0.688c0.577-1.553,5.548-5.092,8.551-6.967l4.663,0.143c0.507,0.059,3.156,0.893,3.707,1.797l0.259,0.42h0.493  c10.79-0.016,31.264,0.006,34.359,0.26l0.057,0.094c0.541,0.885,1.191,1.695,3.208,1.867h13.095  c1.222,1.381,2.143,1.551,3.007,1.436c0.413-0.051,0.64-0.074,1.369,1.105l0.264,0.428h4.938l-0.146,0.146l0.405,0.887l0.258,0.398  l0.518,0.049h19.374l-3.362-6.32L783.433,147.399z M991.4-5.855c-4.745,0-8.593,3.855-8.593,8.604c0,4.737,3.848,8.586,8.593,8.586  c4.753,0,8.6-3.849,8.6-8.586C1000-2,996.153-5.855,991.4-5.855 M991.4,9.472c-3.71,0-6.733-3.017-6.733-6.726  c0-3.716,3.023-6.736,6.733-6.736c3.718,0,6.74,3.021,6.74,6.736C998.142,6.455,995.118,9.472,991.4,9.472 M991.102,47.76  l-0.234-0.424l-0.671-2.072l-1.163-2.864l0.313,0.703l0.404-14.517l-0.388-0.276c-0.712-0.501-0.833-0.794-1.406-2.472l-3.783-9.043  l-2.279-2.295c-1.52-1.283-3.41-2.873-4.623-4.82l-0.255-0.418h-6.368c-0.271-0.387-0.99-1.422-0.99-1.422l-0.509-0.063h-5.367  c-0.264-0.382-0.979-1.417-0.979-1.417l-0.51-0.063h-4.041l-0.291-0.36l-1.346-1.782l-0.493-0.079h-4.184  c-1.646-1.714-4.073-2.731-6.094-3.502c-1.335-0.501-3.141-1.192-3.241-1.713l-0.143-0.716h-4.707  c-0.275-0.375-1.003-1.422-1.003-1.422l-0.497-0.059h-8.354l1.146,1.444c0.412,0.507,9.101,8.774,12.148,11.673v7.772  c-0.04-0.376-0.982,0.377-0.982,0.377l-0.34,0.269l-0.052,0.467v10.738l-0.979,0.383l-0.331,0.26l-0.063,0.467v27.511l0.233,0.481  l0.438,2.211l0.828,2.887l-0.278-0.695l-0.566,9.863l1.334,1.091c-0.178,0.877-0.273,2.164-0.273,3.819  c0,3.122,0.229,6.879,0.331,8.458l0.873,2.134l0.492,1.147v4.074c0,0.908,3.084,10.854,6.158,14.273  c-0.056,0.563-2.513,24.918-2.513,24.918c0.072,0.451,2.804,6.75,2.804,6.75l1.585,3.953c0.314,0.768,1.022,0.799,1.333,0.814  l0.032,0.283c-0.08,0.525-1.713,1.455-4.865,2.74l-1.516,0.631l0.312,0.799c0.009,0.041,1.59,4.285,1.59,7.365l-0.029,0.67  c-0.287,3.354-1.899,6.785-4.288,9.174l-0.84,0.842l1.047,0.568c1.208,0.652,7.824-0.158,10.119-1.24  c0.206-0.096,0.655-0.404,0.979-0.828l1.535,0.699l2.95,0.881c1.729-0.922,4.741-1.732,7.646-2.514  c5.142-1.406,7.865-2.23,8.407-3.598l0.8-0.729l1.835-2.537l2.279-4.373l0.582-1.656l1.454-7.783  c1.188-2.896,1.172-5.994,1.156-8.988c-0.017-2.824-0.024-5.496,1.01-7.92c1.362-5.09-0.153-26.56-0.206-27.474l-0.295,0.719  l0.474-1.475l0.813-3.92l0.938-7.004c0.348-0.072,1.906-1.568,3.151-4.43c0.724-1.347,0.918-2.96,0.918-4.651  c0-0.979-0.061-1.98-0.129-2.969l-0.065-3.629c0.336-0.602,0.99-1.738,0.99-1.738l0.764-1.523l0.278-0.368  c0.429-1.188,0.57-3.944,0.57-7.063c0-5.525-0.434-12.188-0.514-13.301L991.102,47.76z M976.952,69.09  c-1.944,1.035-3.318,9.959-3.318,9.959s-2.9,1.4-2.578,6.284c-0.974,2.446-0.949,30.238-0.949,30.238  c-0.564,3.289-2.264,5.016-3.768,10.176c0.438,8.422-7.067,16.715-7.613,17.313l0.202-66.57c-1.27-0.659-2.744-6.998-2.744-8.884  c0,0-0.716-1.74-1.1-2.369c-0.016,0.568-0.057,0.842-0.121,0.699c-0.233-1.063-0.121-1.087,0.121-0.699  c0.134-3.874-0.558-21.797-0.558-21.797l-0.389-1.768l0.591-5.652c3.795-0.262,4.986,0.095,8.52,0.095  c1.992,0,2.125,2.964,5.48,2.964c0,3.666,3.257,4.375,5.144,7.038c0.61,0.892,1.367,7.968,3.08,8.886V69.09L976.952,69.09z   M993.825,2.651V2.623c1.002-0.406,1.438-1.207,1.438-2.267c0-1.378-1.029-2.506-2.65-2.506h-4.891v9.062h1.996V3.367h1.988  c0.998,0,1.357,0.428,1.516,1.377c0.093,0.719,0.069,1.6,0.313,2.168h1.987c-0.354-0.502-0.34-1.584-0.381-2.145  C995.077,3.848,994.795,2.896,993.825,2.651 M991.893,1.953h-2.174v-2.555h2.174c0.891,0,1.366,0.386,1.366,1.255  C993.259,1.568,992.782,1.953,991.893,1.953 M675.011,131.304c0.13-0.719,0.189-1.463,0.189-2.211c0-1.814-0.314-3.656-0.585-5.236  c-0.162-0.979-0.376-2.234-0.376-2.971l0.089-0.555c1.895-2.426,2.412-5.262,2.412-8.301c0-1.819-0.193-3.721-0.372-5.658  l-0.42-7.097v-6.012c0.21-0.458,0.437-0.963,0.437-0.963l-1.632-2.202l-1.303-1.313c-0.796-1.812-1.066-4.131-1.066-6.424  c0-4.664,1.101-9.241,1.119-9.307l0.134-0.555l-1.678-1.32v-0.127c0-0.438-0.347-1.139-2.461-3.209l-0.565-0.558l-0.688,0.636  c-0.255-0.26-0.541-0.881-0.541-1.278l0.032-0.206c0.429-0.573,1.66-2.524,1.66-4.233l-0.193-1.06  c-0.218-0.519-0.715-1.188-1.867-1.417c-3.645-0.364-5.814-2.113-5.978-2.6c0.864-0.735,5.938-6.752,7.945-10.563l5.097-9.526  c1.078-1.008,1.401-2.496,1.401-4.289c0-1.382-0.193-2.934-0.403-4.593l-0.502-6.065c0-4.159-2.753-11.803-7.237-14.809  c-1.883-1.263-3.823-1.113-4.486-1.029l-0.679-0.539c-0.975-0.658-2.315-1.556-2.695-3.1l-0.146-0.57l-0.582-0.092  c-5.148-0.811-7.599-0.596-11-0.297l-9.183,0.438l-7.21-0.236c-0.129,0-9.328,0.422-11.696,1.772h-7.361l-1.213,1.584l-0.606,2.631  l-0.021,1.365c0,0.564,0.068,0.928,0.578,1.248l0.934,1.178l4.603,4.425l0.131,0.153c-0.493,0.024-1.012,0.049-1.012,0.049  s0.695,0.477,1.286,0.873c0.08,0.592,0.314,0.796,1.316,0.796c0.389,0.214,0.775,0.396,1.156-0.011l0.031-0.061l0.833-0.047  l0.573,0.625l-0.016,0.051l-0.041,1.378l0.101,1.81l-0.949,0.695l-0.347,0.26l-0.179,0.572v34.443  c0.121,0.464,1.616,2.926,1.616,2.926c0.08,1.713,0.13,4.288-0.129,4.789l-1.354,3.085l-0.134,9.938  c0.077,0.392,1.1,2.552,1.11,2.572l-0.008,0.149c0,0.99,0.271,6.546,0.271,6.587c-0.008-0.181-0.348,0.654-1.333,0.743l-0.802,0.072  l-0.148,11.986l-0.295,14.238l0.999,11.246l0.214,2.535c0.654,4.926,0.5,8.072,0.286,12.438l-0.295,10.795  c-0.975,5.092-2.636,11.443-3.104,12.164c-0.646,0.619-2.765,1.568-3.953,2.021l-1.396,0.521l2.239,1.916l0.832,0.746l0.845-0.178  l2.372,0.102c1.911,0.188,3.27,0.264,4.163-0.086c4.744,0.805,12.365,1.654,13.631-0.887c0.9-0.852,1.468-1.037,1.767-1.027  l1.195,0.873c0.47,0.525,0.999,1.127,1.819,1.104c0.562-0.021,1.07-0.336,1.563-0.957c0.566-0.373,5.061-1.242,8.852-1.783  l0.524-0.076l0.183-0.49c0.581-1.563,2.618-3.021,4.781-4.563l1.422-1.033c3.116-2.309,8.723-4.891,8.777-4.92l0.473-0.221  l0.051-0.502c0-0.064,0.532-5.93,1.879-9.297c1.087-2.795,3.884-6.797,3.906-6.828L675.011,131.304 M656.905,120.323  c0.189,1.076-2.068,9.404-2.61,9.771c-0.896,4.424,0.187,9.967-2.102,12.01c-1.852,1.334-4.647,6.355-7.457,6.545l-3.066,2.768  c-1.852,0.74-4.972,1.061-4.972,1.061s3.613-6.477,2.865-5.578c-0.149,1.803-0.355-5.307-0.355-5.307  c0-19.678-0.367-7.723,0.372-12.535c0.143-0.902,0.764-1.176,1.374-1.848v-25.308c-0.94-0.38-1.459-1.212-1.374-2.228  c0.077-0.894,0.529-1.516,1.374-1.851l1.366-6.672c0,0-1.937-7.596,0-10.004c0.314-3.522-0.004-14.614-0.004-14.614l4.34,4.465  c0,0,3.008,2.902,5.537,4.262c0,0,3.567,3.104,2.068,4.545c-1.033,0.732,2.372,3.175,0.032,3.294c0,0,2.36,2.573,1.035,5.219  c1.814,0.965-0.68,5.54-0.68,7.253c0,5.78,2.255,1.723,2.255,8.652c-4.636,3.326,2.393,9.703-0.525,11.773  C658.344,117.265,656.186,119.136,656.905,120.323 M655.692,26.149c-0.447,0.228,1.357,5.114,1.357,5.114  c-1.811,0.964-1.365,10.031-1.365,11.732c-8.146,0.635-6.265,7.396-9.938,8.521c-0.239,0.075-0.857-1.109-3.428,0V24.229  c2.219-1.204,0.828-1.232,1.807-3.814c0.478-0.175,1.266-0.629,1.266-0.629c0.214,0.475,0.214,0.996,0,1.478l5.156-0.739h1.015  c2.062,4.448,3.678,1.994,6.861,3.706L655.692,26.149z M938.026,123.565l-0.578-0.188l-0.981-0.322  c0.052-0.348,0.479-4.055,0.836-4.654l0.157-0.271l-0.021-0.385l-0.396-2.729c-1.31-9.38-1.883-12.774-2.264-13.449l-0.383-0.725  l-1.233,0.578c-0.315-0.185-0.581-1.721-0.683-2.298c-0.139-0.809-0.238-1.399-0.57-1.755c-0.274-0.747-0.408-4.308-0.501-6.7  c-0.178-4.655-0.3-6.777-0.752-7.533l-0.638-2.511l-0.426-2.041l-0.399-1.647l0.009-0.208c0-1.122-0.736-1.398-2.91-2.217  l0.004-0.021l-0.133-1.022c-0.09-1.217-0.23-3.047-2.021-3.676c-3.692-4.644-5.553-4.693-7.93-4.217c0,0-0.577,0.008-1.131,0.008  c0.259-0.355,0.541-0.637,0.541-1.344c0-0.229-0.016-1.617-0.032-2.273c7.574-0.488,13.015-6.642,16.081-18.631l0.029-6.131  c0.254-0.58,0.589-1.324,0.589-1.324l0.53-1.465l0.262-0.49c0.041-0.741,0.211-3.307,0.211-5.545c0-1.453-0.073-2.77-0.283-3.347  l-6.982-14.712l-0.614-0.31l-1.803-1.416c-1.992-1.738-4.72-4.112-7.76-4.514l-2.497-0.088L912.82,4  c-4.595-1.437-10.071-3.175-10.653-3.479l-0.188-0.101l-0.3-0.054h-6.745l-0.291-0.382c-0.595-0.855-0.963-1.102-2.207-1.102  l-3.612,0.971l-19.722,0.513l-0.153,1.75l5.003,1.089c0.388,0.305,0.926,0.728,0.926,0.728c2.444,1.737,8.911,6.337,9.139,9.974  l0.039,0.762l0.404-0.045l2.671,0.219c0.412-0.137,1.617-1.08,1.617-1.08l0.068-0.107c0.517,0.115,2.425,0.587,3.637,0.98  c-2.82,3.712-6.409,6.428-9.138,8.371l-3.447,2.662l0.032,0.295c-0.201,1.65-0.307,4.033-0.307,6.414  c0,2.389,0.104,4.763,0.307,6.405l0.05,0.332l1.305,1.134l-0.008,0.03l-0.021,0.329c0,0.667,0.381,1.389,1.42,2.455  c0.003,0.568,0.067,6.736,0.067,6.736l0.188,0.464l0.255,2.554c0.116,2.18,0.197,2.926,0.648,3.344  c0.471,1.035,0.541,2.745,0.541,3.633l-0.016,0.563l-0.008,0.106l0.246,0.518l0.335,1.718l0.769,2.552l-0.299-0.703v5.078  l0.348,0.489l0.47,1.039c0,0,0.318,0.597,0.564,1.071l0.655,5.74l0.234,0.479l0.152,1.053l0.603,2.047l-0.278-0.644  c0.008,7.625,0.017,19.377,0.017,27.817c0,5.754,0,9.971-0.017,10.293l-0.024,0.447l1.437,1.156  c0.205,1.463,0.318,2.725,0.318,3.613c0,0.938-0.094,1.535-0.238,1.785c-1.839,1.617-6.106,16.188-6.943,19.107v0.057  c0,1.334,1.173,2.117,3.271,3.523c4.099,2.762,11.708,7.881,15.895,19.322l1.02,2.785l0.679-2.877  c1.043-4.432,1.313-7.221,1.313-9.059c0-1.188-0.109-1.969-0.201-2.563l0.142-0.082l1.006-0.967  c0.117-0.549,0.174-1.252,0.174-2.055c0-2.256-0.388-5.344-0.764-8.346l-0.604-5.555c0.935-2.045,1.222-4.994,1.222-8.021  c0-1.977-0.118-3.988-0.271-5.83l-0.845-1.859l-0.348-0.563l-0.004-0.094c0-0.625,0.524-1.229,0.638-1.32l0.271-0.248l0.063-0.396  v-0.137c0-1.213-0.587-6.65-1.536-15.235c-0.849-7.615-1.996-17.911-1.996-19.795l0.012-0.214l0.806-2.354l0.501-0.927  c1.28-2.698,1.652-3.956,1.652-5.338L904.676,76c2.117,1.576,5.101,6.981,6.691,9.928l1,1.842l0.019,0.291  c0,0.942-0.402,3.452-0.714,5.343l-0.729,4.911l0.797,0.161c3.035,0.729,6.766,20.469,6.766,23.209v0.057  c0.112,0.631,0.161,2.324,0.161,4.439c0,4.756-0.243,11.65-0.558,13.326l-2.579,8.105c-1.535,4.336-2.263,6.527-2.263,7.682  l0.097,0.623l0.227,0.564l1.884-0.016c3.608-0.053,5.262-0.082,12.911,7.398c1.071,1.072,5.51,2.486,6.387,2.758l0.94,0.289  l2.995-15.918l0.715-3.131c1.229-2.947,0.274-4.475-0.186-5.223l-0.121-0.004c0.666-3.238,0.873-5.525,0.873-7.189  c0-1.709-0.214-2.771-0.372-3.568c-0.085-0.434-0.153-0.736-0.153-0.998c0-0.393,0.125-0.699,0.48-1.213l0.142-0.223l0.014-0.314  c0-1.422-1.443-4.547-1.904-5.303L938.026,123.565z M914.922,42.068c0,0-0.48,2.447-0.223,4.012  c-0.901,2.101-2.685,8.561-4.11,10.369c-0.707,0.911-3.095,2.516-5.476,2.958c-1.459,0.275-3.771,0-3.771,0V17.922  c0.551-0.037,1.061-0.037,1.719,0c3.277,0,11.64,11.86,11.64,11.86c2.255,4.027,1.37,7.403,1.37,7.403v2.966  C915.624,40.373,915.366,42.297,914.922,42.068 M122.115,242.837c0,3.475-1.283,6.201-3.846,8.18s-5.822,2.967-9.777,2.967  c-5.746,0-10.217-1.617-13.416-4.85l4.644-4.645c2.064,2.064,5.022,3.096,8.876,3.096c4.334,0,6.501-1.514,6.501-4.541  c0-1.375-0.36-2.4-1.083-3.07s-1.824-1.109-3.303-1.316l-4.438-0.619c-6.502-0.895-9.753-4.316-9.753-10.268  c0-3.336,1.152-6.029,3.458-8.076c2.304-2.047,5.418-3.07,9.339-3.07c4.954,0,8.909,1.428,11.868,4.283l-4.541,4.49  c-1.754-1.686-4.266-2.529-7.533-2.529c-1.824,0-3.225,0.438-4.205,1.316c-0.98,0.877-1.471,1.986-1.471,3.328  c0,1.066,0.387,1.961,1.16,2.684c0.774,0.723,1.884,1.186,3.328,1.393l4.335,0.619c3.13,0.447,5.47,1.393,7.018,2.838  C121.168,236.835,122.115,239.433,122.115,242.837z M248.325,223.333h-9.599v30.34h-7.172v-30.34h-9.598v-6.398h26.368V223.333z   M377.14,241.083c0,3.818-1.29,6.924-3.87,9.314s-5.797,3.586-9.649,3.586c-3.854,0-7.069-1.195-9.649-3.586s-3.87-5.496-3.87-9.314  v-24.148h7.173v23.891c0,2.1,0.567,3.75,1.702,4.953c1.136,1.205,2.684,1.807,4.645,1.807c1.96,0,3.517-0.602,4.669-1.807  c1.152-1.203,1.729-2.854,1.729-4.953v-23.891h7.121V241.083z M508.246,235.149c0,4.094-0.104,6.777-0.31,8.049  c-0.448,2.822-1.583,5.145-3.406,6.967c-2.339,2.34-5.573,3.508-9.7,3.508h-13.262v-36.738h13.262c4.127,0,7.361,1.17,9.7,3.508  c1.823,1.824,2.958,4.094,3.406,6.813C508.143,228.493,508.246,231.124,508.246,235.149z M501.073,235.149  c0-2.959-0.086-5.039-0.258-6.244c-0.206-1.41-0.637-2.512-1.29-3.303c-1.238-1.514-3.027-2.27-5.366-2.27h-5.418v23.943h5.418  c2.339,0,4.128-0.758,5.366-2.271c0.653-0.791,1.084-1.943,1.29-3.457C500.987,240.276,501.073,238.142,501.073,235.149z   M619.396,253.673h-7.173v-36.738h7.173V253.673z M750.479,235.304c0,3.99-0.154,6.76-0.465,8.309  c-0.447,2.545-1.514,4.66-3.199,6.346c-2.683,2.684-5.985,4.025-9.907,4.025c-3.956,0-7.275-1.342-9.958-4.025  c-1.652-1.65-2.719-3.768-3.2-6.346c-0.275-1.514-0.413-4.283-0.413-8.309s0.138-6.793,0.413-8.307  c0.481-2.582,1.548-4.697,3.2-6.348c2.683-2.684,6.002-4.025,9.958-4.025c3.922,0,7.225,1.342,9.907,4.025  c1.686,1.686,2.752,3.801,3.199,6.348C750.324,228.544,750.479,231.313,750.479,235.304z M743.307,235.304  c0-2.82-0.035-4.609-0.104-5.367c-0.207-2.27-0.774-3.922-1.703-4.953c-1.17-1.307-2.701-1.961-4.593-1.961  c-1.927,0-3.475,0.654-4.644,1.961c-0.896,1.031-1.445,2.684-1.652,4.953c-0.068,0.619-0.102,2.41-0.102,5.367  c0,2.959,0.033,4.748,0.102,5.365c0.207,2.271,0.757,3.924,1.652,4.955c1.169,1.309,2.717,1.961,4.644,1.961  c2.133,0,3.801-0.826,5.006-2.477C742.842,243.835,743.307,240.567,743.307,235.304z M877.795,242.837  c0,3.475-1.282,6.201-3.845,8.18s-5.822,2.967-9.778,2.967c-5.745,0-10.216-1.617-13.416-4.85l4.645-4.645  c2.064,2.064,5.021,3.096,8.875,3.096c4.335,0,6.502-1.514,6.502-4.541c0-1.375-0.361-2.4-1.084-3.07s-1.823-1.109-3.302-1.316  l-4.438-0.619c-6.502-0.895-9.753-4.316-9.753-10.268c0-3.336,1.152-6.029,3.457-8.076s5.418-3.07,9.34-3.07  c4.953,0,8.909,1.428,11.868,4.283l-4.541,4.49c-1.755-1.686-4.266-2.529-7.533-2.529c-1.824,0-3.226,0.438-4.206,1.316  c-0.98,0.877-1.471,1.986-1.471,3.328c0,1.066,0.388,1.961,1.161,2.684c0.774,0.723,1.884,1.186,3.328,1.393l4.335,0.619  c3.13,0.447,5.47,1.393,7.018,2.838C876.849,236.835,877.795,239.433,877.795,242.837z"/>
</svg>
```